# Save current url with geb

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

I work with tests on `geb` and I have problem. I need to save/print the address of the current page (function `SaveUrl()`).

**Spock Test:**

```
class TestSpec extends GebReportingSpec {
def "Google"() {
    given: "go to google.com"
    to GooglePage

    when: "we at Google home page"
    at GooglePage

    then: "Search Yahoo"
    Search("Yahoo")
    SaveUrl()
    }
}
```

**GooglePage:**

```
class GooglePage extends Page {
    static url = "http://www.google.by"
    static at = { $("title").text() == "Google"}
    static content = {
        theModule { module SearchModule }
    }

def Search(String arg0) {
    theModule.field.value(arg0)
    theModule.search.click()
    }

def SaveUrl() {
    // need implement
    }
}
```

**Modile:**

```
class SearchModule extends Module {
static content = {
    field { $("input", name: "q") }
    search { $("input", name: "btnK") }
    }
}
```

Please help save/print current URL.
Thank You!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [current url getter](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getCurrentUrl%28%29) on WebDriver class. A WebDriver instance is stored as [`driver` property on Browser](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/api/geb/Browser.html#getDriver%28%29). So in a Geb Spock test it is as simple as saying:

```
driver.currentUrl
```

**EDIT**

Since Geb 0.9.3 there is also a [current url getter available on `Browser`](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/api/geb/Browser.html#getCurrentUrl%28%29).